# CSV Helper how to read csv file with several header lines

Tags: c#, .net, csv, header, csvhelper

I am using CsvHelper to write a csv file with multiple header lines, at different positions (the headers have the some number of columns, but different names). The number of rows after each header is different.

Is there any possibility to use CsvHelper to find/iterate over the different header lines inside the csv file (maybe by searching by the name or part of the names for the header columns) and read iteratively the records after each header?

Comment: could you _split_ the CSV-file into several files with one header each?

Comment: That would be of course a possibility, but then I would write from the beginning several files instead of one.But the idea is to use only one csv file, as all the headers have the some structure. Just the name of the header columns and the number of rows after each header is different.

Comment: well, several files would be the nonplusultra of "doing it the clean way". if you don't want the clutter of several files in your directory, maybe bundle them in a zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to do this manually, read line by line and decide what you are going to do.

Example to you start:

> CSV File:
>
> Test1, Test2, Test3
>
> A,1,foo
>
> TestA, TestB, Test3
>
> B,07a0fca2-1b1c-4e44-b1be-c2b05da5afc7,bar

```
void Main()
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<BarMap>();
            var fooRecords = new List<Foo>();
            var barRecords = new List<Bar>();
            while (csv.Read())
            {
                switch (csv.GetField(0))
                {
                    case "A": // Or "Test1"
                        ...
                        break;
                    case "B": // Or "TestA"
                        ...
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown record type.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example and documentation:
[Reading Multiple Record Types](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-record-types/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that helps. I have to change a little bit to be able to read all records until the next header row identified. Another problem is that my csv file has  2 fixed columns and some dynamic columns that are generated from a list. How would the sample change if the row structure cannot be mapped to a fixed structure?

Comment: dynamic records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>();
[Dynamic Records](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/get-dynamic-records/)